# How to convert array to json format objects using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an array like this:

```
["Tom","John"]
```

And I want to convert it to the following json format:

```
["nameList"]:[{"name":"Tom"},{"name":"John"}]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: ["nameList"]:[{"name":"Tom"},{"name":"John"}] is not correct json format

Comment: what you have tried? I think you want `{"nameList":[{"name":"Tom"},{"name":"John"}]}`

Comment: if you want it? {"nameList" : [{"name":"Tom"},{"name":"John"}]}

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `loop` on the existing object, specifying the *json* data for the new AngularJS object as:

```
var data = ["Tom", "John"];

$scope.angularData = {
  'nameList': []
};

angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
  $scope.angularData.nameList.push({
    'name': v
  });
});
```

Watch the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/oqww43h6/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.map` function to make a new array with objects. Then convert the array to json.

```
var namesArray = ["tom", john];

var newArray = namesArray.map(function(item){
   return {'name': item}   
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
JSON.stringify((
     {nameList:[
          {name:"Tom"},
          {name:"John"}
     ]}
))
```